# Como buscar dentro de um arquivo em diferentes subpastas usando grep?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, grep

Como posso fazer um `grep` que busque em um arquivo específico mas dentro de várias subpastas?

Algo como `grep -R "busca" /home/apps/*/teste.php`

O asterisco é a indicação de que quero buscar em todos os diretórios dentro de `/home/apps` mas somente dentro do arquivo `teste.php` que existe dentro dessas subpastas.

Comment: Questões desse tipo cabem no https://unix.stackexchange.com/ ou mesmo no https://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/  - Lembre-se de ler as regras específicas daquela comunidade antes de postar lá. Para futuras questões que estejam no [escopo do site](/help/on-topic) vale a pena entender [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e ler o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O seu comando (`grep -R "busca" /home/apps/*/teste.php`) busca apenas o arquivo `teste.php` nas pastas que estão um nível abaixo de `/home/apps/`.

Ou seja, se o arquivo for `/home/apps/pasta/teste.php`, ele é encontrado. Mas se for `/home/apps/teste.php` ou `/home/apps/pasta/subpasta/teste.php`, estes serão ignorados.

Um jeito de buscar em todas as subpastas é usando a opção `--include` para especificar o nome do arquivo, e indicar a pasta a partir da qual será feita a busca:

```bsh
grep -R "busca" --include="teste.php" /home/apps
```

Assim, ele busca pelos arquivos chamados `teste.php` que estão dentro de `/home/apps` (e a opção `-R` garante que buscará em todas as subpastas).

Outra opção é usar `find` para buscar os arquivos, e em seguida passá-los para `grep`:

```bsh
find /home/apps/ -name "teste.php" | xargs grep "busca"
```

---

Só que ambas as soluções acima também fazem a busca em `/home/apps/teste.php`, caso exista. Mas se a ideia é pegar somente a partir de um determinado nível, você pode usar a opção `-mindepth`:

```bsh
find /home/apps/ -mindepth 2 -name "teste.php" | xargs grep "busca"
```

No caso, `-mindepth 2` faz com que arquivos um nível abaixo da pasta `/home/apps` sejam ignorados. Ou seja, `/home/apps/teste.php` será ignorado, mas `/home/apps/pasta/teste.php` e `/home/apps/pasta/subpasta/teste.php` não.

Comment: Perfeito, consegui, muito obrigado!